# Tasks and Box API

Tags: task, box-api

Does anyone know if there are any plans to add tasks to the api? Like the ability to add or complete tasks? Attach tasks to documents?

Thanks and cheers,

Chad

Comment: This has been available for a while now! http://developers.box.com/docs/#tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are plans to add tasks to the V2 API.   It is not part of our short list to get the V2 API to GA status, but will probably come shortly afterwards.

If you have specific uses for tasks that you'd be willing to share with us, you can let us know more details via email at api at Box dot com.